# Xcode finds nil in optional value and crashes Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been looking on this site for an answer to my question but no matter what I do my compiler still gives me the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I don't know what is causing this seeing as I wrapped up all my code in an `if statement` to ensure that if the value submitted is nil it would print a message.

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var label4: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if textField.text != nil {
        let textFieldInt: Int? = Int(textField.text!)
        let convert = textFieldInt! * 7
        label4.text = String(convert)
    }

    else {
    label4.text = "Please enter a number!"
    }

}
```

I've searched through similar questions and have understood a small amount about what is causing this error but I have yet to find a solution.

Could someone please help me?

I am using Xcode8 with the latest version of Swift.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: You have **not** *wrapped up all my code*. `textFieldInt!` can crash.

Comment: `textFieldInt!` is an optional that you're force unwrapping it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I've look at that question and still can't find a solution to my problem. Not sure what you're trying to insinuate here but I'm not sure what's wrong with asking a question that I can't find answered.

Comment: Either your outlets are not connected or your text cannot be parsed into an `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

You are force unwrapping using `!`. You need to do `if let` or `guard let` to unwrap because `textFieldInt` that you force wrapped may be nil.

You should use this code

```
if let textFieldText = textField.text {
    if let textFieldInt = Int(textFieldText ){
        let convert = textFieldInt * 7
        label4.text = "\(convert)"
    } else{
        print("textFieldInt  is nil")
    }
}else{
    print("text field's text is nil, not too likely")
}
```

Comment: You mean like `if let textFieldInt: Int? = Int(textField.text!)` ?

Comment: @JamesRidley Updated.

Comment: @FangmingNing your inner if statement is not correct. Why do you optional cast an optional int to an int and hence make the return value of your if let optional? You should omit that `...as? Int` part. Optional casting `textField.text` to `String` also makes no sense, since it already returns an optional string.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thank you for the edit, there are some typos

Answer (score 0):

The crash occurs due to `textFieldInt` is `nil`

the problem is that `textField.text` is not number-like String.

```
 let textFieldInt: Int? = Int(textField.text!)
```

That's why `textFieldInt` is `nil` here:

```
        let convert = textFieldInt! * 7
```

to solve this issue I would suggest to use this:

```
if let val = textField.text, let intVal = Int(val) {
    let convert = intVal * 7
    label4.text = String(convert)
}  else {
    label4.text = "Please enter a number!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared textFieldInt as an optional `Int?`  Thus, it's possible for it to be nil. The following will assure it's an `Int`

```
        guard let textFieldInt = textField.text as? Int else { 
            //handle fail case
            return 
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var label4: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

  if textField.text != nil {
      if let textFieldInt: Int? = Int(textField.text!){
       let convert = textFieldInt! * 7
       label4.text = String(convert)
     }

  }

  else {
    label4.text = "Please enter a number!"
  }

}
```